# What is the accuracy of facial recognition possible to achieve using open source neural networks like OpenFace?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, face-recognition

The task is to train ready open source neural network for open-set face recognition  through the database of 10k users with each of them shot for 2-3 images (filmed from a little different angles)

What level of accuracy could be expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataset is somewhat larger than "Labeled Faces in the wild" (around 5000 fases, with 1-240 samples for each face). For that dataset, neural networks have been able to pass 90%. While it depends on the quality of photos, how different the people look, etc., for large numbers 90% is a reasonable estimate. Of course, your results can be worse if the network is too small and images are not preprocessed well (de-rotation of faces is common in good classifiers).

[This paper](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~elm/papers/LFW_survey.pdf) is a survey on systems that have been tested on the above dataset.

Comment: Thanks for answering. When you are talking about 90% level of accuracy do you mean open source neural networks and libs or it's a level of commercial products?

Comment: Open source stuff. Commercial systems, like those from Omron,  report 98% for frontal photos with good illumination. I edited the answer to add a survey paper on the state of the art.

Comment: Can you recommend one of the open source stuff for face recognition or maybe you have positive personal experiences with one of these?

Comment: For learning the basics, OpenCv's Face recognition example is great. https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition was easy to use, while OpenFace seems more accurate.